# Set custom SOAP header using Axis 1.4

Tags: java, .net, web-services, soap, axis

I'm trying to consume a .NET 2.0 web service using Axis. 
I generated the web services client using Eclipse WST Plugin and it seems ok so far.

Here the expected SOAP header:

```
<soap:Header>
<Authentication xmlns="http://mc1.com.br/">
    <User>string</User>
    <Password>string</Password>
</Authentication>
</soap:Header>
```

I didn't find any documentation on how to configure this header from an Axis client.
When I generated the client using Visual Studio C# Express 2008, it generates a class named `Authentication` with two String attributes (`User` and `Password`) and all the client methods receive an object of this class as first parameter, but it did not happen with Axis WS client.

How can I set this header in my client calls?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Maybe you can use `org.apache.axis.client.Stub.setHeader` method? Something like this:

```
MyServiceLocator wsLocator = new MyServiceLocator();
MyServiceSoap ws = wsLocator.getMyServiceSoap(new URL("http://localhost/MyService.asmx"));

//add SOAP header for authentication
SOAPHeaderElement authentication = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://mc1.com.br/","Authentication");
SOAPHeaderElement user = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://mc1.com.br/","User", "string");
SOAPHeaderElement password = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://mc1.com.br/","Password", "string");
authentication.addChild(user);
authentication.addChild(password);
((Stub)ws).setHeader(authentication);

//now you can use ws to invoke web services...
```

Comment: after so many frustrating hours, this is the answer i needed. thanks

Comment: `SOAPHeaderElement authentication = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://mc1.com.br/","Authentication");` This statement gives me and error `cannot initiate abstract class java` how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What if header is having 2 soapElement like this:   <soapenv:Header>
      <kpn:KpnHeader-v2>
                 <kpn:RoutingInfo></kpn:RoutingInfo>   
      </kpn:KpnHeader-v2>
      <oas:Security>
         <username></username>
      </oas:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>

Answer (score 3):

If you have an object representing the `Authentication` container with userid and password, you can do it like so:

```
import org.apache.axis.client.Stub;

//...

MyAuthObj authObj = new MyAuthObj("userid","password");
((Stub) yourServiceObject).setHeader("urn://your/name/space/here", "partName", authObj);
```

Comment: Which kind of object is `MyAuthObj`? Maybe the one that for the OP is `Authentication`? If so how can the client instantiate such an object?... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and solved by the below fragement:

```
ServiceSoapStub clientStub = (ServiceSoapStub)new ServiceLocator().getServiceSoap(url);
org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement header = new org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement("http://www.abc.com/SSsample/","AuthHeader");
SOAPElement node = header.addChildElement("Username");
node.addTextNode("aat");
SOAPElement node2 = header.addChildElement("Password");
node2.addTextNode("sd6890");

((ServiceSoapStub) clientStub).setHeader(header);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used almost the same solution as mentioned before:

```
SOAPHeaderElement cigWsHeader = new SOAPHeaderElement("https://ws.creditinfo.com", "CigWsHeader");
cigWsHeader.addChildElement("UserName").setValue("username");
cigWsHeader.addChildElement("Password").setValue("password");

var port = new ServiceLocator().getServiceSoap(someUrl);
((Stub) port).setHeader(cigWsHeader);
```

And spent hours searching why "Security header not found". And the aswer is... redundant symbol "/" at the namespace: "https://ws.creditinfo.com/" . Seriously! Keep it in mind.